# Why isn't the druid affected by her enchanted cuffs?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, honor-among-thieves

At one point in the film *Dungeons and Dragons: Honor Among Thieves*, prior to being thrown into an arena, the druid and sorcerer in the party are fitted with enchanted cuffs that suppress their spellcasting abilities. At the risk of spoiling the plot, the druid forms an escape plan that involves her using her '*wildshape*' ability to shapeshift into a snake.

Maybe I'm missing something, but shouldn't this ability also be suppressed by the cuffs?

Comment: I can't speak for 5e, but in both 3.5e and 4e *Wild Shape* was a special action, not a spell.  It had no Verbal, Somatic, or Material components and no casting time.

Comment: @DavidW In 5e it’s also not a spell, but the description does state that it’s magical in nature, which AIUI is consistent with previous editions (IIRC, in 3.5e it was a supernatural ability, so it was still affected by things that prevented any magic from happening at all, such as an antimagic field, but could not be dispelled). And this gets into the crux of the issue, it’s still magic even though it’s not a spell, so stuff that suppressed magic (which is what the cuffs actually did in the movie IIRC) would still stop it.

Comment: There's no help in the official novelisation. It doesn't contain the end of the film :-(

Comment: @Valorum- was your rewriting the title to this really necessary?

Comment: The larger plot hole, IMO, is how a (being generous) 10th level sorcerer manages to counterspell [Time Stop](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Time%20Stop)

Comment: @jdunlop by rolling a 19+ charisma check (5e rules), so not great odds but not terrible either

Comment: Based on the answer given, I guess it's a "yes, you are missing something"

Answer (score 60):

During the druid and barbarian's first encounter with the gelatinous cube, the druid plunges her hand with the cuff into the cube. When she pulls her hand out, it is also pulled through the cuff, which remains in the cube.

There's a brief closeup of the cuff stuck in the cube -- here's a clip:

Thus, the druid doesn't have any restrictions later, during the escape plan.

Comment: The barbarian explicitly points that out to make it clear to the viewer. She says something like "Look what you lost instead" or the like and points at the cuff or the druids wrist right after the druid says "Another minute and I would have lost my hand" in the clip (it's not in the clip but was in the version of the movie that screened in my cinema...). Feel free to add that.